# Determine if geolocation is substring of search string

Tags: php, mysql, string, search, sphinx

I have a site with content that is searchable using a search bar that is powered by Sphinx Search (only mentioned because I will end up using Sphinx's geo-search functionality).

Table fields include:

```
Id, title, description, tags, geolocation
```

How can I go about determining if any part of a string contains a reference to a geographic location? The solution I am looking for will likely be performed in PHP and I will then search using Sphinx as I normally would.

For example, if someone searches for any of the following:

```
Car parts in California

Car parts near San Francisco

90210 car parts
```

Then I would like to be able to return a list of all entries that match `car parts` within a certain radius of the desired location.

I am open to any suggestions as to how to make this problem simpler.

Note: the geolocation substring entry by the user is optional. Therefore, the solution needs to determine it's existence and then act accordingly.

Comment: Two questions, 1. What's the geographic area you need to cover(local area, USA, world-wide)? 2. Do you need multiple language support?

Comment: @AlexC The geographic location is worldwide and can be as general as a continent or as specific as a city or zip code (similar to how Google returns a map of locations entered into certain search queries). As for multi language support, everything is in English for the time being.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of APIs you could use for this:

http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/ <-- look at Geodict

http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/placemaker/guide/web-service.html

http://developers.metacarta.com/api/ <-- look at Query Parser

... they perform all the "heavy lifting" for you :)

Alternativly, could make your own with sphinx itself!

Download a copy of geonames database http://www.geonames.org/

Stick it in a database table, and make a sphinx index on it.

Then take your query string and run a SPH_MATCH_ANY query against the 'geo' table.

Then look though the sphinx resultset, and extract any place matches - to make a new query without the placename.

This sphinx index will also return you geocoordinates you can use for the real query :)

(you could optimise it a bit to specifically notice the 'in/near' and either just remove them, or use them to explicitly identify the placename)

Good luck!

(the zip-code handling - could also be done in the same way - put the zip codes in the sphinx index too. there are downloadable copies available online. Or could be handled as special case - looking for a number)

Comment: I wish I could +2.  This seems to be exactly what I was looking for.  I especially love the solution that uses Sphinx.  I can't wait to test it out.  Thanks!

Comment: I'll give him the +2.  This was along the lines I was thinking, but he did it better and sooner.

Comment: When performing the `SPH_MATCH_ANY` against the `geo` table for the query `Springfield, Illinois` I receive results for various `Springfield`'s in many different states. Obviously, Springfield, Illinois is at the top of the list.  Selecting the top result works for this example, but should I always only select the top result for each query? What if the user enters multiple locations?  Just looking for suggestions.